# Add options to data source in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce

I am trying to create a SQL Server Compact 4.0 database to a new project in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

I have followed these steps:

1. Created a Entity Data model diagram (`.edmx`)
2. Right-click on empty area -> `Generate Database From Model...` -> `New Connection...`
3. In the `Choose Data Source` dialog box I only have `SQL Server`, `SQL Server DB file` and `Other`

[image]

I have tried repairing the SQL Server Compact 4.0 installation but nothing changes. Where are the options for this dialog box configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the SQL Server Compact Toolbox, which will enable the SQL Server Compact DDEX provider for the Data Source dialog. Go to the About screen in the Toolbox and Install DDEX providers, a VS restart may be required.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great help